# Wordpress Custom Post Type Query Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, flexslider, advanced-custom-fields

After scratching my head for almost 2 hours, I am unable to resolve the puzzle. Anyone who could help me , I will be highly thankful to him.

I have created a custom post type 'Properties' in wordpress.  I am trying the following code to list the properties in a page. All of it is displaying fine except Images.

```
<?php
$conarg = array (
'post_type' => 'properties',
'order_by' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$condo_query = new WP_Query( $conarg );
    if ( $condo_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php 
            while ( $condo_query->have_posts() ) {
            $condo_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <?php

            $condo_images_max   = 5;
            $condo_items = array();
            for($i=1; $i <= condo_images_max; $i++) {

                    //check if image exits
                $img_attachment_id  = get_field('gallery-image-'.$i);

                if(!empty($img_attachment_id)) {
                    $condo_items[$i] = array(
                        'image' => wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_attachment_id, 'medium')
                    );
                }
            }

            $condo_items_keys = array_keys($condo_items);
        ?>

    <div class="box col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                    for($i=0; $i < count($condo_items) ; $i++) {
                    $image  = $condo_items[$condo_items_keys[$i]]['image'];
                ?>
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="Carousel Image" />
                </li>

                <?php
                }
                ?>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <?php echo '<h2 class="condo-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            echo'<ul class="condo-details">';

            if(get_field('area_range')) {
                echo '<li><span>SQ.FT RANGE:</span> ' . get_field('area_range') . '</li>';
                }

            if(get_field('room_view')) {
                echo '<li><span>ROOM VIEW:</span> ' . get_field('room_view') . '</li>';
                }

            if(get_field('price_range')) {
                echo '<li><span>PRICE RANGE:</span> ' . get_field('price_range') . '</li>';
                }
            ?>


            <a class="condo-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('VIEW DETAILS'); ?></a>

            <?php   
        echo'</ul></div>';
    }
} 
else {
    echo'Sorry! No Condos are available at the moment!';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

?>

Comment: Can you let me know the output of `$img_attachment_id  = get_field('gallery-image-'.$i);`?

Comment: outputs nothing.. thats the actual issue.

Comment: Are you sure your fields have a name of gallery-image-1, gallery-image-2 etc in ACF? Have you already set images for them? Have you told it to save the image ID and not the default of object?

Comment: @NathanDawson   yes they are set like you said. see http://screencast.com/t/mNi4InQM9

Comment: Personally I'd switch to the PRO version and use a repeater field but I'll submit an answer that should help resolve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment it's probably worth switching to the PRO version and using a repeater field.

In your question you're overcomplicating this by unnecessarily building an array and then looping through your array using `for` instead of `foreach`.

Remove the code to build an array and try this instead of your current output code:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <?php // Set maximum number of images to check.
    $condo_images_max = 5;

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $condo_images_max; $i++ ) {

        // Get image ID.
        $image_id = get_field( 'gallery-image-' . $i );

        // Check if image ID was found.
        if ( $image_id ) {
            // Output medium image in an li tag.
            echo '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'medium' ) . </li>';
        }
    } ?> 
</ul>
```

If you need to be able to control the output of the image element and display it in the way you show in your question you can use:

```
...

if ( $image_id ) {
    // Get image source.
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'medium' );

    // Check image source was found.
    if ( $image ) {
        echo '<li><img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="Carousel Image" /></li>';
    }         
}

...
```

There is one issue in doing it this way to be aware of (and one of the reasons I suggested a repeater).

Let's say you have 6 image fields and a property is using all 6. The admin then decides to delete the first image so now the property has 5 images. The code will still work because we're checking an image was found before trying to output it but instead of showing all 5 images you'll only see 4 of them. Image #1 is empty and we've told it to stop looking after image #5.